# GetAdaptersInfo and GetAdaptersAddressess BufferLength Param

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, windows-xp

I've got some legacy code in C++ here that does some things I don't understand. I'm running it in Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition on a machine running Windows XP.

The code uses some Windows functions: [GetAdaptersInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365917(VS.85).aspx) and GetAdaptersAddressess. I realize that the final parameter for both of these is a pointer to the size of the buffer and since it's in_out, it can be changed within the function.

My question is: are these functions supposed to change the buffer length?

In the code I have, every time these functions are called the buffer length variable is initialized to zero, and after the function is called, it's still 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code needs to look something like this:

```
// First get the desired size.
unsigned long outBufLen = 0;
DWORD dwResult = GetAdaptersInfo(NULL, &outBufLen);
if (dwResult == ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW)  // This is what we're expecting
{
    // Now allocate a structure of the requried size.
    PIP_ADAPTER_INFO pIpAdapterInfo = (PIP_ADAPTER_INFO) malloc(outBufLen);
    dwResult = GetAdaptersInfo(pIpAdapterInfo, &outBufLen);
    if (dwResult == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        // Yay!
```

**Edit:** See also Jeremy Friesner's answer for why this code isn't quite enough.

Comment: So GetAdaptersInfo gets the size that the pIpAdapterInfo element would be in the first call, and then in the second call actually gets the Adapter Info?  That's interesting.  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Yes. It's quite common for Windows APIs that fill buffers to work this way.

Answer (score 7):

Of course, the example code in [@RichieHindle's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070351/getadaptersinfo-and-getadaptersaddressess-bufferlength-param/1070481#1070481) contains a race condition.... if the size of the structure Windows wants to return grows after the first call to GetAdaptersInfo() but before the second call to GetAdaptersInfo(), the second call to GetAdaptersInfo() will fail with ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW as well, and your function won't work.

Yes, that does happen in real life -- I've had it happen to me.  If you want the code to be reliable, you need to call GetAdaptersInfo() in a loop, increasing your buffer's size as many times as necessary until the call succeeds.

There has to be a less error-prone way to construct an API... unfortunately Microsoft hasn't yet found it.  :^P

Comment: +1 Good point. And wow, you were spectacularly unlucky to be caught by that!

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, Using Visual studio 6, I used to get the number of adapters by:

```
DWORD drc = GetAdaptersInfo(NULL, &(Buflen = 0L));

if (drc == ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW)
  n = Buflen / sizeof(IP_ADAPTER_INFO);
```

It was all right, for instance for 2 adapters Buflen was set to 1280 and `sizeof(IP_ADAPTER_INFO)` was 640.

Now I am using Visual C++ 2008 Express and my result is truncated because the function still sets Buflen to 1280 but the value of `sizeof(IP_ADAPTER_INFO)` is now 648!

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: I know this is an OLD question, but I just ran into the same problem with a MinGW build. So maybe this helps someone in the future.
The reason is the size of the type time_t.
See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366062%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: The important section: "When using Visual Studio 2005 and later, the time_t datatype defaults to an 8-byte datatype, not the 4-byte datatype used for the LeaseObtained and LeaseExpires members on a 32-bit platform. To properly use the IP_ADAPTER_INFO structure on a 32-bit platform, define _USE_32BIT_TIME_T (use -D _USE_32BIT_TIME_T as an option, for example) when compiling the application to force the time_t datatype to a 4-byte datatype."