# Get IP address of my computer on a local network by way of BSD sockets?

Tags: c, sockets

Since there is no function in BSD sockets to get the IP address, I did client/server program to establish the connection.  One thread for each: server and client.

The IP address returned from "inet_ntoa" with localhost was 127.0.0.1.
But the network says my computer is this 10.0.0.7, and this address is what works.

How do I get the 10.0.0.7 address?
Thx

Here is my code:

```
DWORD WINAPI CIpAddressDlg::Thread_TcpServer(LPVOID iValue)
{
      CIpAddressDlg *pp = (CIpAddressDlg*)iValue;
      CString c;
      char buffer[128]; 
      int sinlen;
      struct sockaddr_in sin; 
      int s, h; 

      sin.sin_family = AF_INET; 
      sin.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
      sin.sin_port = htons(4000);   // Port 

      s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM,0);
      bind(s,(struct sockaddr*)&sin,sizeof(sin));
      listen(s,1);
      sinlen = sizeof(sin);      
      h=accept(s,(struct sockaddr*)&sin,&sinlen );

      //get IP address
      int len = sizeof sin;
      if(::getsockname(h,(struct sockaddr*)&sin,&len) == -1)
            pp->MessageBox("Error local host ip");

      c.Format("%d\nlocal addr %s:%u\n  errno: %d", sin.sin_addr, inet_ntoa(sin.sin_addr),ntohs(sin.sin_port), errno);
      pp->MessageBox(c);

      //verification of send
      recv(h,buffer,sizeof(buffer),0);
      pp->MessageBox(buffer);
      send(h,buffer,strlen(buffer),0);

      ::closesocket(s);
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
DWORD WINAPI CIpAddressDlg::Thread_TcpClient(LPVOID iValue)
{
    CIpAddressDlg *pp = (CIpAddressDlg*)iValue;
    CString c;
      char buffer[128]= "Hello world"; 
      struct sockaddr_in sin; 
      struct hostent *host; 
      int s; 

      host = gethostbyname("localhost");  

      memcpy(&(sin.sin_addr), host->h_addr,host->h_length); 
      sin.sin_family = host->h_addrtype; 
      sin.sin_port = htons(4000);

      s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM,0);                       
      connect(s,  (struct sockaddr*)&sin,sizeof(sin));     

      send(s,buffer,strlen(buffer)+1,0); 
      recv(s,buffer,sizeof(buffer),0);

      ::closesocket(s);     

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the "private"/"LAN" IP of the computer you're running the script on?  Certainly there are easier ways to do this.

Comment: yes!  for the computer I am running the script on

Comment: I'm a linux guy, but what about [GetAdaptersAddresses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365915.aspx)?  The example code provided at the link seems pretty thorough.  It definitely doesn't require all the hassle you went through :-)

Comment: I am running a very old Visual C++ compiler(VS c++ 6.0).  It doesn't look to work.  So that is why I limited it to just "c" and "sockets"

Comment: GetAdaptersInfo? [See "Method Three" here](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/i-n/network/networkinformation/article.php/c5451/Three-ways-to-get-your-MAC-address.htm), [Some sample code here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070351/getadaptersinfo-and-getadaptersaddressess-bufferlength-param)

Comment: As a side note, there is a function in BSD sockets to do exactly this (`getifaddrs`), its just not ported to windows.

Comment: Also [this might help](http://suite101.com/article/socket-programming-gethostbyname-a19557) (using Winsock API)

Comment: Thank you, the last one did it!

Comment: @jedwards - How about turning those into an answer? :)

Comment: Sure, I kind of just threw stuff out there and hoped one would help since I wouldn't be able to test them myself.  Happy to have helped :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are easier ways to get the "private" / "LAN" IP of the machine your program is running on.  Your solution is very *ingenuitive* though.

I think the most straightforward is probably [`GetAdaptersAddresses`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365915.aspx).  The example code on the MSDN page seems pretty thorough.

But if that requires a newer compiler version, consider [`GetAdaptersInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365917%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  See ["Method Three" here](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/i-n/network/networkinformation/article.php/c5451/Three-ways-to-get-your-MAC-address.htm) and [some sample code here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070351/getadaptersinfo-and-getadaptersaddressess-bufferlength-param).

Also, it seems like you could also access the IP address via the WinSock API.  See [this example](http://suite101.com/article/socket-programming-gethostbyname-a19557).

Lastly, just as a sidenote, there is a function in BSD sockets to do exactly this (`getifaddrs()`), its just not ported to Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Despite the intuitive appeal of the concept and, for that matter, widespread belief in said concept, computers do not have IP addresses.

*Interfaces* have IP addresses.

You can get a list of the interfaces and choose the first one.  Unfortunately, getting a list of interfaces in most languages is system dependent.

The usual approach is to just use `0.0.0.0`.