# Change my dynamic IP address by c++

Tags: c++, windows, ip, ip-address, tcp

I've got a dynamic IP address, infact I can change it from my router page (http://192.168.1.1) clicking on release and then renew.

I could made the http request by curl to the http://192.168.1.1 page but this solve the problem only on my computers that use that router.

So I'm interested to know if is there a way to update my IP by c++ without passing through the router page (192.168.1.1).

I've tried also from command line without positive result.
The code I've tried is the following:

```
ipconfig /release

ipconfig /renew
```

I've also tried this code:

```
#ifndef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#endif

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream> 

#pragma comment(lib, "iphlpapi.lib")

#define MALLOC(x) HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, (x)) 
#define FREE(x) HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, (x))

// Before calling IpReleaseAddress and IpRenewAddress we use
// GetInterfaceInfo to retrieve a handle to the adapter

void __cdecl main()
{
    ULONG ulOutBufLen = 0;
    DWORD dwRetVal = 0;
    PIP_INTERFACE_INFO pInfo;

    pInfo = (IP_INTERFACE_INFO *)MALLOC(sizeof(IP_INTERFACE_INFO));

    // Make an initial call to GetInterfaceInfo to get
    // the necessary size into the ulOutBufLen variable
    if (GetInterfaceInfo(pInfo, &ulOutBufLen) == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER) {
        FREE(pInfo);
        pInfo = (IP_INTERFACE_INFO *)MALLOC(ulOutBufLen);
    }

    // Make a second call to GetInterfaceInfo to get the
    // actual data we want
    if ((dwRetVal = GetInterfaceInfo(pInfo, &ulOutBufLen)) == NO_ERROR) {
        printf("\tAdapter Name: %ws\n", pInfo->Adapter[0].Name);
        printf("\tAdapter Index: %ld\n", pInfo->Adapter[0].Index);
        printf("\tNum Adapters: %ld\n", pInfo->NumAdapters);
    }
    else if (dwRetVal == ERROR_NO_DATA) {
        printf("There are no network adapters with IPv4 enabled on the local system\n");
        return;
    }
    else {
        LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
        printf("GetInterfaceInfo failed.\n");

        if (FormatMessage(
            FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER |
            FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
            FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
            NULL,
            dwRetVal,
            MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), // Default language
            (LPTSTR)&lpMsgBuf,
            0,
            NULL)) {
            printf("\tError: %s", lpMsgBuf);
        }
        LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
        return;
    }

    // Call IpReleaseAddress and IpRenewAddress to release and renew
    // the IP address on the first network adapter returned 
    // by the call to GetInterfaceInfo.
    if ((dwRetVal = IpReleaseAddress(&pInfo->Adapter[0])) == NO_ERROR) {
        printf("IP release succeeded.\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("IP release failed: %ld\n", dwRetVal);
    }

    if ((dwRetVal = IpRenewAddress(&pInfo->Adapter[0])) == NO_ERROR) {
        printf("IP renew succeeded.\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("IP renew failed: %ld\n", dwRetVal);
    }

    // Free memory for IP_INTERFACE_INFO 
    if (pInfo != NULL) {
        FREE(pInfo);
    }
    std::cout << ("\n Processo terminato\n");
    std::system("PAUSE");

    return;
}
```

I've DHCP Server enabled whit these values:
DHCP Service State
DHCP State: Enabled
IP iniziale DHCP:   192.168.1.2
IP finale DHCP (Riservato per uso interno): 192.168.1.254

I need run my program on windows XP and Windows 7 platform.

Thank's for your help

Comment: I guess your router runs a DHCP server. In this case you can send a `DHCPRELEASE` packet and request a new ip address.

Comment: I think my router has got a DHCP server, infact I can change my ip by the router page.
Is there a way to send the `DHCPRELEASE` using c++?

Comment: If you want just change ip on your network interface, start from reading this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070351/getadaptersinfo-and-getadaptersaddressess-bufferlength-param and go ahead on MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa366028%28v=vs.85%29.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa366309%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Why do you want to use c++? You could use `ipconfig /release [<Adapter>]` or `ipconfig /release6 [<Adapter>]` https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd197434.aspx If you really want to do it in c++ then use WinApi `IpReleaseAddress` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366056%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I've tried to use `ipconfig /release` and `ipconfig /renew` but it doesn't work. Now I'll try to study the functions IPReleaseAddres and IPRenewAddres. Hoping that it won't be hard :D

Comment: Might have problems regardless. Odds are pretty good the DHCP server will just assign the same address again.

Comment: Is there a way to solve that problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The IP Helper functions include [IPReleaseAddress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366056.aspx) and [IPRenewAddress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366057.aspx) to do exactly this.

You'll need to start by enumerating the network adapters though, and pass the correct adapter's ID to the functions to do that. You usually do that with [GetInterfaceInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365947.aspx).

Comment: I've tried the example code I've found in the links that you suggest me. 
It took me some time because I had to install visual basic.
Anyway the program termiated whit success but the IP was not changed. Can you tell me the reason?
I'll add the code that I've compiled in the first post because it's too long to stay in a comment

Comment: @Carme: The DHCP server is free to assign the same ip address for the new lease. Maybe you can change your hardware address (mac spoofing) and trick the DHCP server to assign you another free ip address. However since its possible through the router webinterface, you can send the correct HTTP packet sequence to your router with c++.

Comment: I've tried to change MAC addres...I obtain a new IPv4 address but not a new public IP addres.

Comment: @Carme Ok, you want a new **public** ip address? The DHCP server in your router only assigns ip addresses in your local network. As I said you can send HTTP packets to your router like your webbrowser and it will do the job for you.

Answer (score 1):

I thounght that changin my dynamic IP I would change also my public IP. But it is not so.
To change my Public IP Addres I haven't to change the dynamic IP, but I need change the ROUTER IP.
Infact the ISP assign an ip for any router connection that will be the public IP for any devides connected.

(For public IP I mean the IP address you can see in http://www.ipmy.it/)

So if I want to change my public IP address I have to change my router IP address.
To change it I have to disconnect and reconnect my router power supply, or I can do it through the router panel ([192.168.1.1](http://http:%5C%5C192.168.1.1)).

So the only automatic solution is to write a program executing that http request.

I wrote it in c++ using libCURL.

Thank's to all for the support.